# How do I maintain a togglebox state after cache-refresh?

Tags: javascript, css

For my website, I developed a day/night theme switch using CSS and Javascript. 
With CSS I use a lot of transitions to make the day/night switch run smooth.
This, however, causes problems when I save the toggle state in my localstorage.

My site saves the theme preference, but whenever I open a new page, the transitions play again. Below is an example of my code:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {

    function darkmode(){
            $('body').addClass('night');
            $('#toggle-box-checkbox').prop("checked", true);
            localStorage.setItem("toggle-box-checkbox", "dark");
    }

    function nodark(){
            $('body').removeClass('night'); 
            $('#toggle-box-checkbox').prop("checked", false);
            localStorage.setItem("toggle-box-checkbox", "light");
        }

    if(localStorage.getItem("toggle-box-checkbox")=="dark")
        darkmode();
    else
        nodark();

    $('#toggle-box-checkbox').change(function(){   

        if ($(this).prop('checked'))
        {
            darkmode();
        }
        else
        {
            nodark();
        }
});

});
```

Whenever I switch to darkmode it manually set's the checkbox from 'false' to 'true'. Is there a way to keep it set to true until I click the switch again?

Comment: It is already `set's the checkbox from 'false' to 'true'`. What do you mean by `Is there a way to keep it set to true until I click the switch again?`

Comment: The way it works now is that it loads the togglebox with status 'false' and then manually sets the status to 'true'. Is there a way to keep it in the 'true' state? (and not load as 'false'), I hope I explain it correctly.

Comment: check `checked` property of checkbox

Comment: thank you! I realize I looked at the problem from a wrong angle. The fact that my togglebox has an animation which is set in the ::after state is what caused the problem.